# Data management webhooks for hub scope

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge

I am developing a webhook for dm.version.added as documented [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/dm.version.added/). According to the docs, the scope has to be 'folder' which allows writing hooks on the project level (i.e., monitoring one project per hook). Will it be possible to write the webhook for hubs level (i.e., monitoring multiple projects with the same webhook)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhooks are for folders, as you mentioned, so you can set up a dm.version.added for the top most folder (`Project Files`) of each project in the hub. Unfortunately, you cannot set up a hub-level webhook.